Error while Inserting Data using Rest API in Zoho Catalyst
I want to insert a record in the Catalyst Datastore table using Rest API. But while inserting the records in table I'm facing an issue of invalid input.
Details which I'm using to insert a record into the table:

"scope": "ZohoCatalyst.tables.rows.CREATE"

API url : "https://api.catalyst.zoho.com/baas/v1/project/project_id/table/table_identifier/row"

A row of JSON data that passed as a request body.
{
    "customer_id": 1001,
    "customer_name": "Guru",
    "Designation": "Tester"
}


The error response that I'm getting while invoking the insert API.
{
    "status": "failure",
    "data": {
        "message": "The input value is not readable. Please check your input",
        "error_code": "INVALID_INPUT"
    }
}




You are trying to insert a row by sending the request body as a JSON object. Hence, you are facing this issue. To resolve this issue, kindly try sending the request body in JSON Array format. You can find their Sample Insert API help documentation here for the same. Also, you can check on the sample request body as given below.
For Example:
[
{
"customer_id": 1001,
"customer_name": "Guru",
"Designation": "Tester"
}
]
